# Admob opening http threads

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, admob

I'm testing admob in my application.
when my Main Activity calls

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

with R.layout.main containing an AdView (Thats my code)

```
     < com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"<br/>
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"<br/>
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"<br/>
                         ads:adUnitId="-----------------"<br/>
ads:adSize="BANNER" <br/>
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

If I check the ddms while executing just after the `setContentView()` call appears 11 threads http ("http1","http2",...."http11" ) and an `AsyncTask` as waiting threads. Is that normal?